# Как будет выглядеть результат запроса?

Tags: sql, select

Существует 2 таблицы (account и client), содержащие 4 и 2 записи соответственно
Какой результат вернет SQL запрос:

```sql
Select  1 client_id, 2 account_id  from client, account
```

Comment: dbfiddle/sqlfiddle откройте да проверьте. зы: вернет 8 строк 1-2

Comment: можете почитать про кросс соединения по ANSI sql-89

Answer (score 0):

Вернет все возможные комбинации строк этих двух таблиц

Comment: вы проверили? а то мне вот что-то кажется что не вернет

Comment: Вас смущает "from client, account" ? Это рабочая схема

Comment: меня ничего не смущает. я вижу что `select 1 client_id` (читай `1 AS client_id`) всегда будет выводить значение 1 в  столбец с именем `client_id`. аналогично со вторым. ваше утверждение было бы верным, если запрос был `select client_id, account_id` но он не такой.

Comment: Да кстати, не внимательно прочитал, спасибо за замечание.